# sparql filter query with resource name

Tags: rdf, sparql

I have a paragraph that is split into phrases.  I need to filter the sparql query to get the strings of the first and the second phrase only.

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX ns: <http://example.org/ns#>
SELECT ?string1 ?string2 
WHERE
{
  ?paragraph ns:phrase ?phrase1 ,
                       ?phrase2 .
  ?phrase1 rdfs:label ?string1 .
  ?phrase2 rdfs:label ?string2 .
}
LIMIT 100
```

The only order i have of the phrases is encoded in the rdf resource `<p23969797xX>`:

```
    @base <http://example.org/base/> .
    @prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
    @prefix ns: <http://example.org/ns#> .

    <p23969797x1>   ns:phrase   <p23969797x2> .
    <p23969797x1>   ns:phrase   <p23969797x3> .
    <p23969797x1>   ns:phrase   <p23969797x4> .
    <p23969797x2>   rdfs:label  "string1" .
    <p23969797x3>   rdfs:label  "string2" .
    <p23969797x4>   rdfs:label  "string3" .
```

Comment: If there is no explicit ordering information in your RDF then there is no way to limit to the first two phrases.  It would be possible to write a query that gets just two phrases but it would be implemented dependent (and potentially non-deterministic) which phrases you received i.e. you would not be guaranteed to receive the first two phrases.  RDF is a set data model not a list so ordering of the data is completely irrelevant, a triple simply exists or does not exist.

Comment: Btw it is helpful if you actually post a complete working example, both your query and data had syntax errors in them and lacked any prefix/base declarations.  I have made some definitions up to make this a viable question

Answer (score 2):

If the order is in the name of the URI, you can check its string conversion and only pick URIs ending with "x1" and "x2".

```
 PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
 PREFIX ns: <http://example.org/ns#>
 SELECT ?string1 ?string2 
 WHERE
 {
   ?paragraph ns:phrase ?phrase1 ,
                   ?phrase2 .
   ?phrase1 rdfs:label ?string1 .
   ?phrase2 rdfs:label ?string2 .
   FILTER(strEnds(str(?phrase1), "x1") && strEnds(str(?phrase1), "x2") )
 }
 LIMIT 100
```